# List with modification button for each element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a React Redux app that shows a list of cars parked in a chosen parking, but not all cars, only those with a property called parked=true.

I'm using APIs to modify and get elements from the database, now I need a PUT request to modify the state of each car to parked=false and so remove it from the list. I already have the PUT function (which I linked below).

My problem is that the function needs the ID of the element and I don't know how to pass it to the function.

Here's my code (voiture means car):

this is my function in my actions.js

```
export const ParkedModifié =(voiture) => ({
    type: VOITURE_MODIFIED,
    voiture
});
//PUT request
export const notParked = (id)=>{
    return(dispatch)=>{
        return requests.put(
            `/voitures/${id}`,
            {
                parked: false
            }
        ).then(response => dispatch(ParkedModifié(response)))
    }
}
```

and here's my carList.js

```
        return (

            <div className="card mb-3 mt-3 shadow-sm">
                { voitureList.map(voiture => {
                    return (

                      <div className="card-body border-bottom" key={voiture.id}>
                         <p className="card-text mb-0">
                             {voiture.matricule}
                         </p>
                         <p className="card-text">
                         <small className="text-muted">{timeago().format(voiture.gareele)}</small>
                         </p>

                         <Button color="danger" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Change</Button>
                         </div>         
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following pattern is what I always use. That way, you don t pass a function with different reference each time. In this case which would lead your `Button` component to rerender for nothing, whenever this parent component renders.

So what we do here is to pass `onSubmit` and read from 'data-' attribute inside.

```
        onSubmit = event => {
           const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id')
           // use id however you want
        }


        return (

        <div className="card mb-3 mt-3 shadow-sm">
            { voitureList.map(voiture => {
                return (

                  <div className="card-body border-bottom" key={voiture.id}>
                     <p className="card-text mb-0">
                         {voiture.matricule}
                     </p>
                     <p className="card-text">
                     <small className="text-muted">{timeago().format(voiture.gareele)}</small>
                     </p>

                     <Button 
                        color="danger" 
                        data-id={voiture.id}
                        onClick={this.onSubmit}
                     >
                       Change
                     </Button>
                     </div>         
                );
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I added   ```onSubmit = event => {
        const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id')
        return notParked(id);
     }``` and even though It doesn't give me an error, the value still doesn't change inside the database

Comment: a quick console.log show that it gets the id without any problem, the problem must be in my function itself

Comment: Yep. Definetely.

Answer (score 0):

The are many solutions but very simple solution is here.

I assume that your **voiture** object has an propery named **id** so (check the onClick function):

```
        return (

        <div className="card mb-3 mt-3 shadow-sm">
            { voitureList.map(voiture => {
                return (

                  <div className="card-body border-bottom" key={voiture.id}>
                     <p className="card-text mb-0">
                         {voiture.matricule}
                     </p>
                     <p className="card-text">
                     <small className="text-muted">{timeago().format(voiture.gareele)}</small>
                     </p>

                     <Button color="danger" onClick={e=>{this.onSubmit(voiture.id)}}>Change</Button>
                     </div>         
                );
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

feel free to ask more question in comment.

Comment: weird, it gives me ```Uncaught TypeError: notParked is not a function``` even though I imported the function and added     ```onSubmit(id){
        const {notParked}= this.props;
        return notParked(id);
    }```